# How to uninstall maths input panel in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, math-input-panel

I'm in the mood for removing bloat. Stuff like DVD maker and this nifty little tool called Math input panel. I just don't have a use for it.

Is there anyway to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Panel> Programs and Features(Icon view)> Turn Windows Features On or Off> untick Tablet PC Components